# jQuery mobile javascript on multiple HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am building a jQuery Mobile site with multiple HTML files and use some externe javascript files. This all work fine, the scripts ran on the pages after loading etc. But when I'm calling the second page directly, there is no jquery and jquery-mobile javascript file included (because I only include it in the index.html).

What is the best solution to include the javascript files, that it runs on both ways (directly and over the links in index.html) and with the least duplicaton.

The actual setup looks like this:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
      ..............
    </head>

    <body>     
        <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" id="navigation">
               <a href="trainings.html">Training</a>
            </ul>               
        </div><!-- /panel -->   

        <div data-role="page" id="main-page">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>News</h1>
                <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
                <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon" rel="external">Settings</a>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="false" data-inset="false" id="list">

                </ul>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        ... Project specific import ...
        <script>
            $(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
              $("#left-panel").panel();
            });

            $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#main-page", function() {
                getNewsFromUrl(getAPIUrl() + '/content.php', 'news.html');
            });     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

trainings.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slidebars Basic Template</title>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="trainings">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Trainings</h1>
                <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
                <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon" rel="external">Settings</a>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="false" data-inset="false" id="trainingList">

                </ul>
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <script>            
                $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#trainings", function() {
                    getSigninObjectFromUrl(getAPIUrl() + '/training.php', 'trainingRiege');
                });         
            </script>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I call ./trainings.html directly, the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ' appears, that is understandable for me, but how can I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `footer.html` which you should include in every view at the end. This footer should have your javascript files and functions.

Comment: something like this: `$('#footerDiv').load('Shared/Footer.html').trigger("create");`

Answer (score 0):

With `JQueryMobile`, you make a mobile application, not a mobile website. Your app is written in `index.html` and its resources. Other HTML files are here to split all HTML of your app in multiple files.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean, if I create a new html file, it should be decoupled from other html files?

Comment: With JQueryMobile, a page is a `div` with a `data-role="page"` and you can declare multiple in the main application page (`index.html`) and one per external page (`training.html`). If your application contains hundred of page, use external page can be lighter than hundred of `div` with a `data-role="page"`. Externals pages aren't standalone.

Comment: exactly, I create external pages regarding this, but I don't want to include the same javascript on each html file